# How do I apply a MINIMUM value to a Kendo grid column input box?

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-grid

Code:

```
function directorsOrRecipients(e)
{
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: { url: "http:...xxxx" + e.data.AwardTitleId, type: "GET" }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "namefirstlast",
                    fields: {
                        "namefirstlast": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "directorsequence": { editable: true, type: "number" },
                        "isonballot": { editable: true, type: "boolean" },
                        "concatenation": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "MoreNames": { editable: true, type: "number" },
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "namefirstlast", title: "Name", editor: namesAutoComplete },
            { field: "directorsequence", title: "Director Sequence", format: "{0:n0}" },
            { field: "isonballot", title: "On ballot?" },
            { field: "concatenation", title: "Concatenation" },
            { field: "MoreNames", title: "More names?", format: "{0:n0}"},
            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }],
        sortable: true,
        editable: "inline",
        toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add New Director/Recipient" }]
    });
}
```

I want to make sure the user can only enter numbers that are 0 or greater on the MoreNames column. No negative numbers.

Please note, this grid gets generated by Kendo so it's not a simple HTML structure that I created.

This is the DOM object for the text box I'm concerned with:

```
<input type="text" name="MoreNames" data-type="number" data-bind="value:MoreNames" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" class="k-input" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;">
```

I tried selecting this object and adding an attribute of "min" but I cannot select it which leads me to believe I'm selecting it incorrectly.

This is what I tried:

```
$("[name='MoreNames']").attr("min", "0");
```

Can someone give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "namefirstlast",
        fields: {
        "namefirstlast": { editable: true, type: "string" },
        "directorsequence": { editable: true, type: "number" },
        "isonballot": { editable: true, type: "boolean" },
        "concatenation": { editable: true, type: "string" },
        "MoreNames": { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
      }
    },
  }
},
```